# Plotting Data to WinForms Chart XY(Time, Int)

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am new to WinForms and would like to seek help with learning in plotting data points.

I have a graph and I initialize it with this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var _chartArea = chrtAdamHistory.ChartAreas[0];
    var _chartSeries = chrtAdamHistory.Series[0];
    var _currDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Set X Axis Properties
    _chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
    _chartArea.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
    _chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 30;
    _chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 
            new DateTime(_currDateTime.Year, _currDateTime.Month, _currDateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0).ToOADate();
    _chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 
            new DateTime(_currDateTime.Year, _currDateTime.Month, _currDateTime.Day, _currDateTime.Hour, 
            _currDateTime.Minute, _currDateTime.Second).ToOADate();

    //Set Y Axis Properties
    _chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    _chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 500;
    _chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 50;

    //Set Series Properties
    _chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    _chartSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
    _chartSeries.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
}
```

The chart will look like this:

[image]

Now this is where I'm stuck. I don't know how will I add a data point when the `X Axis` is a `Time`. Can anybody show me how or point me to the right direction?

Comment: Since minimum and maximum were given as doubles you need to compute double from the datetimes as well: `chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.ToOADate(), intValue);`

Comment: Note that this will sit at the very end of the chart and not really show as a spline need at least two points!! See my other comment to Kamil's answer!

Comment: I think everyone should watch closely for the 1st half hour and respond to any comments or answers. This is not a requirement of the site but imo of basic politeness of folk who are seeking help. I tend to downvote not before at least a day has passed, though.. - But then maybe that's just me, who is not even sure how polite your moniker is, which put unpleasant images in my mind. (Just kidding)

Comment: I strongly disagree both on general terms and wrt the site rules . This is directly from the help pages: _Post the question and respond to feedback

After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!_ But otoh, being patient is also required behaviour. So I'll compromise and delete one comment but not the others ;-)

Comment: @TaW: Where does that statement have an explicit time requirement?

Comment: Come on! _A bit_ clearly is less than 2+ hours.

Comment: @TaW Apologies if I seemed impolite, I posted this last night before dinner and thought "I'll give it some time and check back tomorrow at work." Anyway, thank you for your suggestion, I will try this later when I get home and post an update here.

Comment: No problem, if we know. Adding a comment would have made the situation clear.. I hope my hints will help.

Comment: @TaW I tried what you suggested last night and it worked. The `ToOADate()` is what I was missing. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all sorts of Properties in a `Chart` are set to `Auto`, which makes life easier.  But to gain full control one has to set some of them to the values one actually wants.

You did that for the axes' `Minimun`&`Maximum` values and, as one can see, it works fine. But one of the consequences is that now your data must fall into the **ranges** you have set out for display.

This is simple for numbers, as all values in a `Chart` are `double` internally. But when working with `Date`, `DateTime` etc., things can get tricky.

While one can add `DateTime` values directly they still will be converted to `double` internally. You have chosen to add them actually as `double` by converting `DateTime` values via the `ToOADate` function. But you also told the chart that the x-values will be `Time`. This is confusing, as there is not `Time` type in C#. (And it is not just us but more importantly the `Chart` control that gets confused ;-)

To add `DataPoints` now you need to do either:

- use the same conversion to their x-values or else they will not fall into the range of your chart.

Here is an example that adds a few data points.:

```
chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.AddHours(-2).ToOADate(), intValue);   
chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.AddHours(-1).ToOADate(), intValue + 12);
chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.ToOADate(), intValue + 17);
```

- or you can add `DateTime` values directly, without the `ToOADate` conversion, if and only if you tell the chart to **either** expect those **or** to work on `Auto`.

Example:

```
 _chartSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;      // either that or..
 _chartSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;  // ..that will work
```

To get a feeling for the internal ranges of `DateTime` values it is instructive to look at the large double that results from  `DateTime.Now.ToOADate()` btw; atm it was: `43291.412605081`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
DateTime timeValue = DateTime.Now; // for example
Int32 intValue = 324;

chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue, int32value);
```

Comment: Since the charttype is spline adding another point will help a lot. Also making it a little earlier than the maximum ;-) - Since minimum and maximum were given as doubles you need to compute double from the datetimes as well: `chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.ToOADate(), intValue);chrtAdamHistory.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeValue.AddHours(-1).ToOADate(), intValue);`

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the values.
what did you actually try? Maybe missing the invalidate?

```
    for (int i=0; i < 1440; i++)
    {
        _chartSeries.Points.AddXY(i, f(i));
    }
    chrtAdamHistory.Invalidate();
```

Comment: What I was missing was the `ToOADate()` as per @TaWs comment.